# OSX Java App Bundle works on one Mac, but not on another.

Tags: java, macos, bundle

I've written a java app, and packaged it into an OSX App Bundle, using the appbundler ANT task from Oracle. The app bundle works fine on the machine it was developed on (a MacBook Pro), but when I copy it to my MacBook Air it fails to launch with an error saying "Application 'MyApp' cannot be opened". No other diagnostics or information at all.

Both Macs are running the latest build of Yosemite, both have "Run apps from any location" enabled in the Security preferences, and both have Java 1.8 installed. If I copy the Jars directly to the MacBook Air, and double-click the main class Jar, the app launches correctly - so it's something to do with the bundling, not the java app itself.

Any ideas where to start debugging this?

Comment: If it helps, here's the App Bundle: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B2nBmaa4Eo41QnlMNWNPREJvcEk&usp=sharing

(the app is a Picasa Sync client for OSX - beware that it's still under development... :)) Will be putting it on github soon).

Comment: Did you check the console to see whether there are any errors when trying to launch the application? And what happens if you start the launcher using the shell?

Comment: Thanks, I haven't tried launching the bundle from the command-line; I'll try that tonight. Is there a way to see any errors etc when launching the bundle through Finder? (I"m relatively new to Macs...). When you say "using the shell", do you just mean via terminal?

Comment: How are you copying the bundle from one machine to the other? It may be that the stub in Contents/MacOS is losing its execute permission bit during the transfer.

Comment: By "check the console" we mean Console.app, which shows system log messages and also anything a double-clicked app prints to its stdout/stderr

Comment: I'm copying via a sync'd GDrive folder. So you may be right - perhaps the permissions aren't right. I'll try copying it using AirDrop, or zipping it up. I'll also have a look at the Console - thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Okay, so thanks Ian Roberts - looks like you've hit the nail on the head. I copied the file across via AirDrop rather than syncing up to and back down from GDrive, and it launches successfully. So I suspect you were right about the execute permissions. If you want to post that as the answer, I'll accept it so you can get the points. :)

Comment: @IanRoberts - can you copy your comment to an answer, so I can accept? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The app bundle works fine on the machine it was developed on (a MacBook Pro), but when I copy it to my MacBook Air it fails to launch

Then the problem is likely to be in the way you copied the app bundle between the two machines - whatever mechanism you use to do the copying you need to ensure that it preserves the permission settings on the files in the bundle, in particular that the executable stub in `Contents/MacOS` remains executable on the target system.  If you pack the `.app` into a `.zip` file (right click the app in Finder, "Compress (name of app)" and copy the zip file instead of the `.app` directory itself then that should preserve the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you have multiple versions of Java installed on one or both Macs? If so, have you checked what your JAVA_HOME is set to? The /usr/libexec/java_home script is useful for figuring out what different Java installations you have, e.g. 
`java_home -V`

[Apple java_home docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/java_home.1.html)

Comment: The appbundler task doesn't care about what JDKs you have installed. Its launcher stub uses either an embedded JRE inside the app bundle or the single public JRE under the hard coded path of `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin`

Comment: Interesting. Which one are you using (embedded or public)?

Comment: I'm not embedding the JRE in the app bundle.